# How does JavaScript know when a Promises callback function is ready to be executed?

Tags: javascript, promise, stack, task, es6-promise

I know that there is a message-queue and that JavaScript is single-threaded. And there's also an event-loop, taking messages from the queue and doing some work.

When you create a promise, and this promise is being kept in the message queue, when or how does the loop know when it's resolved (or rejected). Is it permanently asking, if the status is not "pending" or is the promise itself queuing to the message-queue when it is resolved or rejected?

#### Update:

After some research, I think I got it wrong. It is not the promise itself but the XHR-request that is actually blocking and running **in its own thread** to not block the main execution thread. So only the main execution thread is single-threaded and the XHR-thread will queue the callbacks to the main-thread when the XHR request gets a result (or fails).

So, corresponding to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), is the promise itself being kept in the stack and will push the callback function to the queue when it is settled?

Comment: Code somewhere in the application explicitly calls either the `resolve()` or `reject()` callback passed in to the handler function used when the Promise was created.

Comment: Why exactly do you care? Is there a problem with some code? Or are you just curious about implementation details?

Comment: I think OP is asking if any other thread owned by browser is keeping a track of the Asynchronous operation like negotiating with N/w.

Comment: Have you considered [reading the spec](https://promisesaplus.com/#the-promise-resolution-procedure)?

Comment: Related article on [microtasks](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/).

Comment: What do you mean by "*is the promise itself being kept in the stack*"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, corresponding to [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), is the promise itself being kept in the stack and will push the callback function to the queue when it is settled?

The following quotation comes from the [Related article on microtasks](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/) suggested by [nem035](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3928341/nem035):

> <sub>Once a promise settles, or if it has already settled, it queues a *microtask* for its reactionary callbacks. This ensures promise callbacks are async even if the promise has already settled.</sub> <sup>[1](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/)</sup>

Try going through the animated step-by-step diagrams,

[image: animated gif of going through the steps]

After the seventh step it reaches this point:

[image: promise then added to Microtasks queue]

So one can conclude that *the promise itself* is not kept in the stack, but the *Promise then* (callback) is added to the queue of Microtasks, which are processed after the stack becomes empty.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>https://jakearchibald.com/2015/tasks-microtasks-queues-and-schedules/</sub>

Answer (score 1):

The promise will schedule the relevant function calls on the queue when it is getting resolved.
There is no polling involved, that would be pretty inefficient.

Comment: What does schedule mean? Will it check again in 10ms?
I mean, the http-request itself is sync and waiting explicitly for an answer from the server. But JavaScript does not wait, instead it puts it back on the "queue" and goes on with other tasks. But when and why will it check back, if the request is finished, the promise resolved and the callback can be executed?

Comment: It means "send a message to the event loop that it should fire the promise callback". That's where the responsibility of the promise implementation ends. The event loop will execute the next task when there are message on the queue and nothing is currently running.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that there is a message-queue and that JavaScript is single-threaded. And there's also an event-loop, taking messages from the queue and doing some work.
>
> When you create a promise, and this promise is being kept in the message queue, when or how does the loop know when it's resolved (or rejected). Is it permanently asking, if the status is not "pending" or is the promise itself queuing to the message-queue when it is resolved or rejected?

Promise are not "kept in the message queue", which contains only micro-tasks. The event loop knows nothing about promises. It merely picks micro-tasks off the queue for execution.

When a promise fulfills or rejects, the promise library puts tasks onto the queue for all the attached `then` or `catch` handlers. (If a `then` or `catch` handler is attached after the promise fulfills or rejects, then the task is put on the queue immediately.)